# How to generate values between 2 values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My data looks like below

```
with test(col) as (
    select  '01-06' from dual union all
    select  '45-52' from dual
    ) select col from test ;
```

Required OP

```
COL
01
02
.
.
.
06
45
46
.
.
52
```

Actually my table count is 20 thousand. I used connect by but its very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate values using recursive query:

```
with test(col) as (
    select  '01-06' from dual union all
    select  '45-52' from dual
), bounds (l,u) as (
  select to_number(substr(col,1,2)), to_number(substr(col,4,2)) from test
), r (l,u) as (
  select l,u from bounds
  union all
  select r.l + 1, r.u from r where r.l < r.u
)
select to_char(l,'00') from r order by l;
```

(edit substr expressions appropriately if any value is not 2-digit)

Answer (score 0):

Saying "I used connect by but its very slow" without posting code you wrote doesn't help much. I *presume* you did it wrong, i.e. got too many duplicate values which slowed things down. See if this `connect by` option helps.

```
SQL> with test (col)
  2  as
  3    (select '1-6' from dual
  4     union all
  5     select '45-52' from dual
  6    )
  7  select lpad(to_number(substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-') - 1)) + column_value - 1, 2, '0') val
  8  from test cross join
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= to_number(substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1)) -
 11                                            to_number(substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-') - 1)) + 1
 12                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

VAL
---
01
02
03
04
05
06
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```